# Fatal Error with fetch_assoc inside a function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I truly need your help. I have seen answers and even followed advice as previously posted but NO SOLUTIONS SHOW how to use fetch associated array using `PREPARED STATEMENTS` so I am not trying to submit an already answered question. I have followed suggestions to others questions but I am still getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /xxx/xxxxxx.php on line 75

I am showing you the old code using MySQL and how I have changed it to MySQLi using prepared statements, but I am still getting the same Fatal Error. Can someone please help me, I am going crazy and I truly need to find out what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
//*******************************************************************
//      OLD CODE: 
//          Called by: $theme=$log->get_theme(); 
//*******************************************************************
class redirect
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function get_theme()
    {
        $rs=mysql_query("select * from theme where status='yes'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0)
        {
            $data=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
            return $data['theme_name'];
        }

    }
}

//*********************************************************************
//      OLD CODE: 
//          Called by: $theme=$log->get_theme($cn);
//*********************************************************************

class redirect
{
    public $cn;

    function __construct()
    {

    }
    function get_theme($cn)
    {
        $themeStatus = 'yes';

        if ($stmt = $cn->prepare("SELECT * FROM theme WHERE status = ? "))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $themeStatus);
                $result = $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                if ($stmt->num_rows >= "1")
                {
                    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();     // ERROR LINE
                    return $data['theme_name'];
                }
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Failed to execute prepared statement: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `$cn` applied? I mean how do you set it when you uses this class?

Comment: Also `public $cn;` is irrelevant at this point of your code because do you don't assign it like `$this->cn = $cn;` How you have it now, you don't need the `public $cn;`

Comment: I am using it like this:   $log=new redirect();
$thm=$log->get_theme($cn);

Comment: I know but how do you create `$cn`?

Comment: mysqli_real_connect($cn, SERVERNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASENAME, NULL, NULL, MYSQL_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE))

Comment: Have you tested that your `$cn` outside of your class works properly before you inject it into the method?

Comment: Yes $cn works if I use bind_result with a variable... but I need to use Select * in the statement...

Comment: Out of curiosity have you ever tried using pdo? I find it so much easier to use and automate

Answer (score 2):

The [mysqli_stmt::execute](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) method returns only bool by definition. So calling `$result->any_method_name()` will fail because `$result` is a boolean value.

To get the values from a prepared statement using the MySQLi library you bind your target variables with `$stmt->bind_result(...)` and then use `$stmt->fetch()` in a while loop to get the result of your query in your bound variables. And after that you switch from MySQLi to [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) because it has a better API regarding this…

Comment: Thanks for your help Progman, but I am trying to not have to use variables for each column as they are too many... so the way the original code is done, it brings in the entire row into and array call $data and then gets each column by association $data[column_name]. I am trying to do the same.